# In which folder should I keep my custom functions file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, function

I have some custom functions in 'custom_functions.php' which I call from my controllers.

my 'custom_functions.php' code is like :

```
class Custom_functions extends CI_Controller  {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

public function data($first, $next) {
// other codes start from here
}
}
```

I kept that file in application/libraries and loaded in controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('custom_functions');
    }

// other codes start from here
}
```

then my custom function worked but the pagination wasn't working.

I get an error message:

> ```
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$pagination
>
> Filename: views/index.php
>
> Line Number: 27
> ```

While the view file 27th line is:

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

if I remove

```
$this->load->library('custom_functions');
```

then the pagination line works. why this happens ? did I do wrong to load my custom function or I kept my custom function in wrong folder ? in which folder should I keep my 'custom_functions.php' file ?

Comment: Take a look at this link to learn how to make your custom library class correctly http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html. You might not be supposed to extend CI_Controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate your library

```
class sample_lib
{
  private $CI=null
  function __construct()
  {
    $this->CI=& get_instance();
  }
}

class Custom_functions  {
    private $CI = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI=& get_instance();
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI->load->model('model');
        $this->CI->load->library('session');
    }

    public function data( $first, $next ) {
        // other codes start from here
    }
}
```

then to call in your controller:

```
echo $this->Custom_functions->data( $first, $next );
```

Comment: that threw error that my class has no parent so can't access parent. So I did >>   class Custom_functions{ public function __construct() {$this->CI=& get_instance(); $this->CI->load->model('model');$this->CI->load->library('session'); }  and accessed model inside of my function like>> $nextdata = $this->CI->music_model->data($nextarray);  now its working.thanks for your help

Comment: if you edit your answer 'class Custom_functions  {}' codes then I'll accept the answer.

Comment: please remove 'parent::__construct();' this line. this throws>> Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in F:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\application\libraries\custom_functions.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

when you are creating a library you are not supposed to extent it with CI_Controller class. Hence you library would contain following code

class Custom_functions{

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    //and you cannot you '$this' while working in the library functions so
    $CI =& get_instance();
    //now use $CI instead of $this
    $CI->load->model('model');
    $CI->load->library('session');
}

public function data($first, $next) {
    // other codes start from here
}
```

}

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in F:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\application\libraries\custom_functions.php on line 12